# Cannot import KotlinCompile in custom gradle plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

I am trying to create a custom gradle plugin, to add dependecies and modify KotlinOptions. However i cannot import KotlinOptions in this custom plugin file.

```
class GreetingPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
Please advise